# How can I get the last value of a column in my dataset in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

In the given table how to get the last value of a particular column in a dataset

```
Roll No Name Index  Score
1       ab1    1    23
2       ab2    2    43
3       ab3    3    42
```

Here we have to pick the Last Row Score value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The first thing we have to create a custom index column in the table

2) Then we have to use the below formula to get the last Row Score value Score value

```
CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(Table[Score], 1), FILTER(ALL(Table), Table[Index] = MAX(Table[Index])))
```

The result would be 42.